# `return this` in jQuery functions, with correct (preserved) chainability

Tags: jquery, return, settimeout, chaining

I had the need for a wait function, began with the following:

```
var delay = (function() {
    return function(callback, ms) {
        setTimeout(callback, ms || 1000);
    };
})();

delay(function() {
    $('#foo').animate({
        height: 180
    }, 1000);
});
```

ported then to jQuery:

```
jQuery.fn.wait = function(callback, seconds) {
    return this.each(function() {
        return setTimeout(callback, seconds || 1000);
    });
};

$('#second').wait(function() {
    $('#second').addClass('foo'); // works well
});​
```

and ended up in confusion:

```
$('#second').wait(function() {
    $(this).addClass('foo'); // `this` will not work here
});​
```

...where's the problem with my last instantiation, or better how can i fix it? `this` looks here at the `window`-object, not to the actual `#second`-element...

Apart from that, is it possible to let the "chain" only go further, if the timeout is at 0? So that if we have the following scenario, the class will only added if the timer is ended:

```
$('#second').wait().addClass('foo');
```

Comment: use of `this` inside the `setTimeout`...`this` is `window`

Comment: Yap, thanks, @SLaks has refutes this problem already... Any ideas for the problem in my last sentence?

Comment: is still not a chaining problem... you still get the chainability, the element itself is returned from your plugin. Context within the `setTimeout` is different problem. Add the class in success callback of the animation

Comment: this plugin does what you want:  http://creativecouple.github.com/jquery-timing/. Use it or study how it handles situation. You can also use jQuery deffered  http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/

Comment: hmm... nice plugin, but a bit too big for a small problem ;-) however, i'll take a look at this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why `this` doesn't give you the element you want is because you're trying to use it in a function for which you did not set a context, try

```
jQuery.fn.wait = function(callback, seconds) {
    return this.each(function() {
        var self = this
        return setTimeout(function(){
                   callback.call(self);
               }, seconds || 1000);
    });
};
```

Comment: Yap, thanks, @SLaks has refutes this problem already... Any ideas for the problem in last sentence?

Comment: @yckart you say `According to this`(in bold), according to what exactly?

Comment: English is not my real native language, sorry for the misleading! I've updated my question...

Answer (score 0):

That has nothing to do with chaining.
Chaining means calling additional jQuery methods on the *return value* of your method.  (`$(...).wait(...).somethingElse()`).
Your method already supports chaining because it returns `this` (through `this.each()`, which is itself chainable).

You're asking how to call the callback with a specific `this` value:

```
var self = this;
callback.call(self);
```

Comment: Read my last sentences... that's a chaining problem! However, thanks for your answer! ;)